# Virtualbox Shortcut to box in Elementary OS

Tags: virtualbox, elementary-os, desktop-shortcuts

I am using ElementaryOS and installed VirtualBox. When I try to create shortcut to a specific box (right click > Create Shortcut on Desktop) nothing really happens.
How do I make shortcut and place it in Plank?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since elementary OS doesn't provide a traditional desktop, where you can place files (or shortcuts), the default desktop directory is linked to the home directory of your user (you can check it with the command `/usr/bin/xdg-user-dir desktop`).

So, your created shortcut should be in this directory. Once you have found it, just drag&drop it into Plank.

### Alternative workaround:

Instead of clicking at `Create shortcut on Desktop`, click at `Open in filemanager`. Your filemanager should open in the folder, which is containing your VM.
Drag&drop your VM (it should be the blue icon) into Plank. That should do the trick, too :)

Comment: The desktop folder is really my home folder, but I do not see the shortcut there.

Comment: @IvanDokov hmm... maybe VirtualBox ignores the default folder settings and tries place the shortcut into a folder named `Desktop`. Create temporarily a such named folder in your home and try to create a shortcut in VirtualBox again.

Comment: It definitely works the way I described it, take a look at this [short video](https://youtu.be/gJrYuNXwZtM) I created.

Comment: I did exactly the same, no shortcut.

Comment: What version of VirtualBox do you use? Mine is the newest from from their PPA: 4.3.26 r98988

Comment: I'm not at home and cannot check the version right now, but I am pretty sure I download it from the official website. I will try to alternative method later today.

Comment: The alternative method works!

Comment: Actually I have another problem now. I place the icon, it works. When I start the machine the icon changes. Take a look at this image http://i.imgur.com/WZn8RgL.jpg

Comment: got any ideas why this happened?